# how to customize iveiw tabpane's width in vue language?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, iview

In official statements, the tab component of view in vue is like that:

[image: official statement example]

its code is :

```
<template>
    <Tabs type="card">
        <TabPane label="标签一">标签一的内容</TabPane>
        <TabPane label="标签二">标签二的内容</TabPane>
        <TabPane label="标签三">标签三的内容</TabPane>
    </Tabs>
</template>
```

But i want to make the tabpane label wider like this:

[image: what i want to achieve]

how can i customize its width???

Comment: Any code for someone to work with?

Comment: @Syfer code is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see other styles on official web:

去看看官方文档：
[https://www.iviewui.com/components/tabs#其它样式](https://www.iviewui.com/components/tabs#%E5%85%B6%E5%AE%83%E6%A0%B7%E5%BC%8F)

[image]